# '1004': ZOrder method of OLEObject class failed - Change OLEObjects zOrder

Tags: vba, excel

Just want to know if I can change the ZOrder of an OLEObject in excel VBA I have tried the following lines of code

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
...
ws.OLEObjects("toeBox").ZOrder msoBringToFront
```

and I get the following error message:

*Run-Time error '1004': ZOrder method of OLEObject class failed*

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Dan

Comment: Zorder is a method of a Shape or ShapeRange object.  Try `ws.Shapes("toeBox").ZOrder msoBringToFront`

Comment: @Tim Thanks heaps! That was too easy! I didn't even think to reference it as a shape. I really appreciate that help :)